# Death to the Timer Reset!

Tags: feature-request, rate-limiting

Everytime I hit a rate limit (doing legitimate things) I am slapped in the face *two* times:

1. I have to wait
2. The timer will reset each time I try

I will concede that there must be a reason for timer resets. The team would not have added them without reason.

Feature request: No timer resets for users with >= 1000 rep. Even better, increase all rate limits by dividing the minimum interval by 5 or so. Show the timer ticking down.

The probability that a high rep user is engaging in vandalism is extremely low. Let's stop punching them in the face.

Comment: 100 rep = High rep user ? One answer can get you there. Also you get 100 on every site with the association bonus without even having to know what the site is about. Disagree

Comment: Make it 1000 then. I'm happy with all numbers as long as they are below mine :)

Comment: I hit this a lot with comment votes. I'm fine with waiting 5 seconds, but keeping on waiting 5 seconds because I get impatient is annoying

Comment: First can we sort out whether the timer reset is a slap in the face or a punch in the face?

Comment: @BilltheLizard The punch comes first, then the slap just adds insult to injury.

Comment: The most triggered timers (at least for me) are short. 5 seconds for deleting comments are the most annoying and that is easy enough to wait it out.

Comment: The best proposal I saw about this problem is simply showing the timer. It would make sense with this.

Comment: I do not understand how six people can be *in favour* of the timer.

Comment: It's a symptom of our "fast" paced society that we are impatient to wait 5 seconds ;)

Comment: +1 for either removing *the reset*, or an explaination of its purpose.

Comment: @Yve If we added up all the 5 secondses (secondses, is that right!?) we'd have had enough time to .... watch a lot of tv and argue about things that don't matter

Comment: @RichardTingle wonder if someone can write some code to see how many 5 secondes in total we wait and how many episodes of (first we have to vote and agree on a TV show) we have missed as a result of this ;)

Answer (score 30):

Totally agreed. At least ease it for 10k users or something.

This is what the timer reset feels like **every single time:**

[image]

Comment: So, re: Bill's question in the comments to the question; does that mean it's more like a punch than a slap?

Comment: @Andrew I'd say it's both. A punch-slap, if you will.

Comment: Downvoted. 10k do not necessarily make a person a quick shooter/thinker.

Comment: @DeerHunter and forcing users to wait 15 seconds, and *another* 15 seconds if they submit before they have passed, and *another*  (get a wristwatch so you can count the seconds!), ad nauseam... will make them think more deeply, and post better comments? Yeah right.

Comment: Maybe it was SE's idea of [throttling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strangulation)...